# Rails migrate from legacy db and convert falsy db field to default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I am performing a comprehensive rebuild of an application I have in Rails. The older version (we'll call it "Legacy") permitted data to be stored for interpretation as being falsy and truthy. I no longer wish for these fields to be interpreted that way.

I have a custom Rake task I have written for for the new application to siphon the data from the Legacy DB and insert that data into the new DB model.

The problem stems from boolean columns I am migrating from the Legacy DB model in PG to the new model in the new PG DB.

Let's say the two models look like the following:

**OLD MODEL**

```
create_table "table_name", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string    "name"
    t.boolean   "is_alive"
end
```

**NEW MODEL**

```
create_table "new_table_name", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string  "new_name"
    t.boolean "is_dead",    default: false, null: false
end
```

And let's say my custom rake task looks similar to the following:

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Migrate old records to new model."
  task :migrate_old_records_to_new_model, [] => :environment do

  Model.find_each do |oldness|
    NewModel.find_or_initialize_by(oldness.name) do |newness|
      puts "\n\tCreating new updated record for #{oldness.name}"

      newness.new_name    = oldness.name
      newness.is_dead     = oldness.is_alive
    end
  end
```

When I attempt to do a conversion from the Legacy DB I get a `PG::NotNullViolation` on the boolean column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing would be to do this:

```
newness.is_dead     = !oldness.is_alive
```

Your `null: false` in the table definition is telling PG that the field can never be null. The legacy data seems to contain null values. Just assigning them over to the new model is breaking the DB constraint.

I know! You are thinking "But I told PG that the default value is `false`!" Yes. True. However, ActiveRecord is *explicitly* telling PG to set that field to `NULL` and PG complies, ignoring the default ...but not the constraint! Were the field/value to be omitted from the insert statement, then the implied default would be used rather than leaving the field as `NULL`.

A better solution would be to add some `before_save` validation in the new model that sets these default values to avoid similar circumstances in the future.

You would do that like this:

```
class NewModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :ensure_is_dead_is_not_null

  def ensure_is_dead_is_not_null
    is_dead = false if is_dead.nil?
    true
  end
end
```

We need to make this `before_save` callback (`ensure_is_dead_is_not_null`) always return `true` because:

> If a before_* callback returns false, all the later callbacks and the associated action are cancelled.

Ref: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Also, depending on how you are handling value assignments and model implementation, you might want to set the defaults on `after_initialize` rather than `before_save`. If you do, remember that `after_initialize`  each time that Ruby initializesand instance (each time a record is loaded from the DB), so you will want to ensure that you are not blindly clobbering valid values that get loaded from the DB.

Comment: Your answer is spot on! Not only is it simple to implement the basic recommendation, but adding `before_save` validation is a big help as well. Thanks!